# PHP SESSION array getting deleted while redirecting from one folder to another

Tags: php, session

Okay I dont know what mistake I'm doing. I've used SESSION variables in past too without any problem but it doesnt seem to work this time.

Here is code from my protected_page.php (page where user is redirected after login is successful).

```
<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
        <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
        <p>
            This is an example protected page.  To access this page, users
            must be logged in.  At some stage, we'll also check the role of
            the user, so pages will be able to determine the type of user
            authorised to access the page.
            </br></br>
            <a href="add/home.php">Add new user!</a>
        </p>
        <p>Logout & return to <a href="includes/logout.php">login page</a></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>
            <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="includes/logout.php">login</a>.
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The function login_check() checks weather user has logged in properly with right credentials or not. If yes, it returns true.

There is another function namely login() which is called during login process and matches credentials with entered credentials. If true, it then stores 'username' in $_SESSION variable.

When I click on "Add new user!" It sends me to add/home.php page, but there is o $_SESSION variable.

```
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
    <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
    <h1>Add user!</h1>
    <?php
    if (!empty($error_msg)) {
        echo $error_msg;
    }
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li>Emails must have a valid email format</li>
    </ul>
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
            method="post" 
            name="registration_form">
        Full Name: <input type='text' 
            name='fullname' 
            id='fullname' /><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
        Project Name: <input type="text"
                         name="project" 
                         id="project"/><br>
        Phone Number: <input type="text" 
                                 name="phone" 
                                 id="phone" /><br>
        <input type="submit" 
               value="Submit"  /> 
    </form>
    <p>Logout & return to <a href="../includes/logout.php">login page</a></p>
    <?php else : echo "7"; ?>
        <p>
            <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="../includes/logout.php">login</a>.
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It always prints I dont ve enough credentials to view this page.

I also ve introduced sec_session_start() function atop both pages. (protected_page.php & add/home.php). sec_session_start() is user defined custom session starting function.

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
$secure = SECURE;
// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;
// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}
// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    $secure,
    $httponly);
// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

}

I don't know what I'm doing wrong this time. Must be a silly mistake. Thanks in advance. :)

For any further details do inform me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have session_start() on all your .php page on top of the page.

Make sure you have it. Even if you have that in a function it may put it too far to the bottom.

You have this going on:

```
session_name($session_name);
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

You need to have session_start as the first thing on the page. Make sure that function 
isn't firing off too far from the top of the page.

Comment: My sec_session_start() is in file functions.php and I've included it at top of each php file. After include_once'' my 1st line is sec_session_start() always. Still I get the error.

Comment: looks like in sec_session_start calls the session_start after a bunch of code. try to move it to the top or get rid of it and put it outside of the function to be the absolute first to test things out to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Okay here is what I did. I got rid of include_once 'functions.php' and instead copied the content of sec_session_start() and login_check() inside 'add/home.php' but still the problem is persisting. I even used session_start() instead of sec_session_start() but of no use.

Comment: this is sounding more like an server issue then; maybe the session isn't getting created on the server end. Most server/php conf put session information in the /tmp directory. I don't know what your situation is hosting wise; but if you have access to the command line make sure session files sess_ is being created in the /tmp dir. if you're unsure of the path, look at your php.ini file to get the exact path